# Email Settings API - Delegation Examples

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am in the process of doing my Java Coding to create delegators for my users via API. On the [Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#delegation_examples), the examples given for Java coding still use the `sample.appsforyourdomain.gmailsettings.GmailSettingsService` library.

My first question is, is this library or sample JAR file still usable with the new OAuth2.0? If it is, where can I download the file from?

Secondly, I am trying to register delegates for the users on my domain and after registration, I would also like to change the settings of the  opened conversations to "Leave conversation unread when opened by others". Is this possible by API?

Comment: You can check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/libraries-samples?hl=en#emailsettings for email settings api client library. Regarding your second question, I dont think you can mark read email to unread. But you can mark as "read" https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SGC. I checked a little more online and found the method to delete emails. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/delete... Regarding the usage of the sample.apssforyourdomain matter (which I think is old and not updated on the Google Reference page), I will check out the site you gave and try to look for the required solution there...